# Shiny app user input throwing warning: "invalid factor level"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a R/Shiny app that takes 9 user inputs, creates a data frame with these inputs, passes the data frame to the predict() function along with a pre-trained random forest model, then returns a probability or prediction.

One of the 9 user inputs is in the form of a radio button and the result is captured in the variable `fever_input`. This variable seems to cause the server to throw the following warning when I generate test user input:

```
Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 4L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Printing the variable results in `[1] "Yes"`.

Despite this, when I call `str(test_df)` which is the data frame constructed from the single observation with 9 variables, I see NA for `fever`. Result below:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ age               : int 23
 $ female            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2
 $ white             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2
 $ bmi               : num 33
 $ peak_bili_pre_ercp: num 1
 $ dm                : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2
 $ fever             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA
 $ stone_on_any_comp : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2
 $ max_cbd_dia_noninv: num 9
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Thanks in advance!

Code below...

UI code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Does my patient have choledocholithiasis?"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
        numericInput("age_input", label="Age: ", min = 18, max = 96, value = NULL),
        radioButtons("sex_input", "Sex", choices = c("Male", "Female")),
        selectInput("race_input", "Race", choices = c("White", "Hispanic", "African-American", "Asian", "Other")),
        numericInput("bmi_input", "BMI", min = 18, max = 75, value = NULL),
        numericInput("bili_input", "Peak total bilirubin", min = 3.84, max = 29.7, value = NULL)
    ),
    column(4, 
        radioButtons("dm_input", "Has diabetes", choices = c("Yes", "No")),
        radioButtons("fever_input", "Has fever", choices = c("Yes", "No")),
        radioButtons("stone_noninv_input", "Evidence of choledocholithiasis on US, CT, or MRCP", choices = c("Yes", "No")),
        numericInput("cbd_dia_input", "Maximum CBD diameter measured on US or MRCP", min = 3.58, max = 19, value = NULL)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8, 
        actionButton("submit_button", "Compute!", class = "btn-lg btn-success"),
        align = "center"
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    print("Debug")

    observeEvent(input$submit_button, ({
        print("Button triggered")

        validate(
            need(input$age_input, 'Please enter an age.'),
            need(input$bmi_input, 'Please enter a BMI.'),
            need(input$bili_input, 'Please enter a bilirubin value.'),
            need(input$cbd_dia_input, 'Please enter a CBD diameter.')
        )

        test_df <- data.frame(age = integer(),
            female = factor(levels = c(0,1)),
            white = factor(levels = c(0,1)),
            bmi = double(),
            peak_bili_pre_ercp = double(),
            dm = factor(levels = c(0,1)),
            fever = factor(levels = c(0,1)),
            stone_on_any_comp = factor(levels = c(0,1)),
            max_cbd_dia_noninv = double(),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )

        print(input$fever_input)

        test_df[nrow(test_df)+1,] <- c(age = input$age_input,
                female = factor(ifelse(input$sex_input=="Female", 1, 0)),
                white = factor(ifelse(input$race_input=="White", 1, 0)),
                bmi = input$bmi_input,
                dm = factor(ifelse(input$dm_input=="Yes", 1, 0)),
                fever = factor(ifelse(input$fever_input=="Yes", 1, 0)),
                peak_bili_pre_ercp = input$bili_input,
                stone_on_any_comp = factor(ifelse(input$stone_noninv_input=="Yes", 1, 0)),
                max_cbd_dia_noninv = input$cbd_dia_input
        )

        str(test_df)
        print(test_df)

    })
    )  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't create empty dataframe and add rows to it.
- I am not sure why you need variables as factors but I have kept them as it is.
- `ifelse(condition, 1, 0)` can be simplified to `as.integer(condition)`.
- In `server` function I print `print(test_df)` so that you can see the created dataframe.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Does my patient have choledocholithiasis?"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           numericInput("age_input", label="Age: ", min = 18, max = 96, value = NULL),
           radioButtons("sex_input", "Sex", choices = c("Male", "Female")),
           selectInput("race_input", "Race", choices = c("White", "Hispanic", "African-American", "Asian", "Other")),
           numericInput("bmi_input", "BMI", min = 18, max = 75, value = NULL),
           numericInput("bili_input", "Peak total bilirubin", min = 3.84, max = 29.7, value = NULL)
    ),
    column(4, 
           radioButtons("dm_input", "Has diabetes", choices = c("Yes", "No")),
           radioButtons("fever_input", "Has fever", choices = c("Yes", "No")),
           radioButtons("stone_noninv_input", "Evidence of choledocholithiasis on US, CT, or MRCP", choices = c("Yes", "No")),
           numericInput("cbd_dia_input", "Maximum CBD diameter measured on US or MRCP", min = 3.58, max = 19, value = NULL)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8, 
           actionButton("submit_button", "Compute!", class = "btn-lg btn-success"),
           align = "center"
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  print("Debug")
  
  observeEvent(input$submit_button, ({
    print("Button triggered")
    
    validate(
      need(input$age_input, 'Please enter an age.'),
      need(input$bmi_input, 'Please enter a BMI.'),
      need(input$bili_input, 'Please enter a bilirubin value.'),
      need(input$cbd_dia_input, 'Please enter a CBD diameter.')
    )
    
   

    
    test_df <- data.frame(age = input$age_input,
              female = factor(as.integer(input$sex_input=="Female")),
              white = factor(as.integer(input$race_input=="White")),
              bmi = input$bmi_input,
              dm = factor(as.integer(input$dm_input=="Yes")),
              fever = factor(as.integer(input$fever_input=="Yes")),
              peak_bili_pre_ercp = input$bili_input,
              stone_on_any_comp = factor(as.integer(input$stone_noninv_input=="Yes")),
              max_cbd_dia_noninv = input$cbd_dia_input
    )
    print(test_df)
  })
  )  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Initially I declared an empty dataset so that I could set 2 levels for each factor (to match the training dataset used to train my model) but I realize now I can just do that inline when creating the dataframe from web input.